# How do I set up Protobuf for my VB.net application?

Tags: vb.net, arrays, protobuf-net, save

So, this may seem very elementary for you guys but I am officially stumped.  I am trying to save some data in my application to a file using protobuf (suggested to me by some peers) but I can't seem to find any documentation for it and what I can find always gives me some weird error.  I have an array declared as follows:

```
Private Terrain(,,) As TiledTerrain
```

The TiledTerrain class looks like this:

```
Public Class TiledTerrain

    Public X As Integer
    Public Y As Integer

    Public Texture_X As Integer
    Public Texture_Y As Integer

End Class
```

Pretty dog-on simple right?  Well, I can't seem to figure out how to save my `Terrain` array to a file using Protobuf?

The `Terrain` array is just a simple 3 dimensional array (about 100x100x2).  Each cell of the array may or may not actually contain a value (`TiledTerrain`) and if it doesn't it will contain "`Nothing`".

Can anybody explain to me in full on how I should go about doing this?  I've currently referenced `protobuf-net.dll` and `protobuf-net.Extensions.dll` because I don't really know which to use...

Thanks for any help!

-A Moron Among Geniuses :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first read [Getting Started](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/GettingStarted) which describes the simplest scenario, using attributes. VB has slightly different syntax for attributes, which you are probably more familiar with than me -  but the concept is the same.

There are alternatives, note:

- in v2 the model can be configured entirey at runtime if you want, without the need for any attributes
- if the type looks like an obvious "tuple" (including, importantly, a constructor that takes a parameter that matches every public member), it will use the constructor order to infer a contract

There is a problem though; protobuf-net does not currently support multi-dimensional arrays. It can of course be added, but as with all features: it doesn't exist until it gets written. The reason this isn't supported directly is that the underlying protobuf specification (by Google) does not support this. It would work if flattened into a vector (1-dimensional zero-based array). If you want help with an example, let me know.